# cp command time discrepancy

Tags: linux, cp

Im not sure exactly what category to put this in.

I have tried to do the following with a file that is 7.7GB on my system Centos 5.5

```
time cp original copy
```

and

```
time cp copy copy2
```

The copy of the copy is about half the time of the copy of the original.

I thought maybe the OS was cacheing or something, so I went to another directory and copied a few small files and stuff, and went back to make the copy of the copy again, and it was still way faster.

Any ideas whats going on here? Is the OS caching the file or something?

What made me notice this problem is that I have some code that processes this file. I wanted to test it on two files, so I just made a copy. I then noticed that the original file takes the longest to process on. What kind of diagnostics can I run on this?

Answer (score 1):

The OS doesn't cache the file so much as it caches the disk blocks it read.

There's a couple of ways to try and account for caching when running timing tests.  You could try to flush the OS disk buffers by allocating a huge amount of memory (I usually run something like `perl -e '"\0"x1024x1024x1024'` to do this);  `free` before and after should give you an idea of how much data the OS has cached (under the `buffers` and `cached` columns).

Or when you time your run, ignore the system time - that will be primarily I/O - and just watch the user time.  Of course, different runs may be very well dealing with different amounts of data so you would expect there to be different amounts of I/O.

The most reliable way is to run the test several times and use the fastest time as the value to compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
time cp original copy
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
time cp copy copy2
```